# Can Angular Reactive Forms Be Made to Create All Elements in a FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm building a form using reactive forms in Angular 7.

First let me get something off of my chest. The information in the Forms portion of the Angular Guide is not the easiest thing to understand, especially the reactive forms portion. Maybe the reason I'm asking this question is that I actually have no clue what reactive forms are supposed to do/give me.

Anyhow...

I have created a UI that has some top level form controls along with a section that allows for multiple items to be added/removed by the user.

Here is how I'm modeling some data. The thing has an array, pretty much like every other dynamic nested array example.

```
export interface IInterestingChoice{
  description: string;
  outcome: string;
}

export interface IMyDataThing {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  lifeChoices: IInterestingChoice[];
}
```

So I've gone and created the component and defined a `FormGroup`:

```
export class SadComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input()
  public data: IMyDataThing;

  public theForm: FormGroup;

  public get lifeChoices() {
    return this.theForm.get("lifeChoices") as FormArray;
  }

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.theForm = formBuilder.group({
      firstName: [null, Validators.required],
      lastName: [null, Validators.required],
      lifeChoices: formBuilder.array([
        formBuilder.group({
          description: [null, Validators.required],
          outcome: [null]
        })
      ])
    });
  }

  onNgInit() {
    this.theForm.patchValue(this.data);
  }

  iWantToSaveThis() {
    const newDataState = this.form.value;

    Object.assign(this.data, newDataState); 
  }
}
```

When the component loads with no data passed to it, the fields are blank and as the user enters data validation occurs. I can add/remove. On the `form` element I have `(submit)="iWantToSaveThis()"`. Data is saved and I smile (slightly).

So then data gets set to the `data` property because a user has filled out the form in the previously and is loading the view again:

```
{
  firstName: "Mike",
  lastName: "G",
  lifeChoices: [
    {
      description: "College",
      outcome: "Degree"
    },
    {
      description: "Software engineering job",
      outcome: "Depression"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now when the UI draws I get only the first position of the array in the form.

**WHY?**

From what I understand I need to change the `ngOnInit` to do something like this:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.theForm.patchValue(this.data);

    for (const choice of this.data.lifeChoices) {
      this.lifeChoices.push(this.formBuilder.group({
        description: [choice.description, Validators.required],
        outcome: [choice.outcome]
      });
    }
  }
```

This seems absolutely pointless to me. What it appears is that we've gone to the JavaScript middle ages. We decomposed our data and assigned it to form values to finally call submit to POST it to an endpoint when the user was done. We could use a `<button type="reset">Be Gone!</button>` to clear the form without doing any further interaction.

Is the only thing that we get from reactive forms the immutable state of the data in the form? Isn't that why I'm using ngrx?!

So, to make this less of a rant, I want to know if there is a way to make the nested array on the `FormGroup` pick up the fact that it has an empty object and that every other object that is patched in should follow the same format, like a template.

*and yes, I get it. Lighten up...*

Here's an app in action: https://angular-pmugex.stackblitz.io

(editor: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmugex)

Comment: FWIW, an alternative is to store form controls within your array, as per: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wlzh3f. Obviously this might not work for your use case and you lose the nice subscription benefits of form group or form array (which I find very useful in some situations), but at least it's clear what's going on? Then when the user hits submit, you just process / save the bits you want from your original object?

Comment: Sorry - I see what you're trying to do now. As lifeChoices is an array, I think its a job for https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray rather than form group.

Comment: Might be worth a look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-form-array-ng6. I've got to have my dinner but if it's any help give me a shout and I'll do a proper example.

Comment: Mike G can you provide a minimal repro on Stackblitz? I think I might be able to help you out :)

Comment: Here's an example app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmugex

Comment: the actual ***why*** of the question is fairly obvious...because the built form only has one formgroup if you add more the data populates like in this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkbzyv